# errors running cucumber on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cucumber

I'm working through the homeworks for the UC Berkeley SaaS class, and have been trying to do the assignments on my Macbook rather than the EC2 or VM.

Anyway, I am having trouble getting cucumber to run. I am using `rvm use 1.9.2` to set the ruby environment, and running in a bash shell. I was able to run hw2, which consisted of running and modifying a rails app.

I have run `rails g install:cucumber` to success.

When I run cucumber, I get this error:

```
/Users/glenn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
/Users/glenn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
/Users/glenn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/Users/glenn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch.rb:35:in `<top (required)>'
```

Any ideas???

---

After further research, I am able to successfully run cucumber via rake, like this: `rake cucumber:all`

Can somebody explain what is going on?  Why does cucumber not run "on its own" like in the class lecture, but it will run via rake on my system?